# How to start an enumerate without new line

Tags: enumerate

I want to start an enumerate after some words and I don't want to change to a new line. The style is like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \noindent Start an enumerate (1) The first line\\
  (2) The second line\\
  (3) The second line.
\end{document}
```

But how to make it using package `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  Start an enumerate 
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item The first line is a new line.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

What about this? I assume you want all items but the first to start on a new line, hence my use of `itemjoin=\\`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

  Start an enumeration:
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*),itemjoin=\\]
    \item The first item doesn't start on a new line.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
  \end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another way where we define a new list type named `mylist` (same output as above):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=(\arabic*),itemjoin=\\}

\begin{document}

  Start an enumeration:
  \begin{mylist}
    \item The first item doesn't start on a new line.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
  \end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I added another way.

Comment: Ok, thanks a second time. I once didn't know the parameter itemjoin. You've done me a great favour!

Comment: Excuse me，how to handle the nested enumerate with inline option. I put an mwe here, where `enumerate*` nesting `enumerate` will cause an error.
```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}


  \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*),itemjoin=\\]
    \item The first item doesn't start on a new line.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item ee
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate*}
  

\end{document} 
```

Comment: AFAICT, you can't use a non-inline list environment like `enumerate` inside an inline one like `enumerate*`, but you can use `enumerate*` for the inner list. The following works: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*),itemjoin=\\]
\item
  The first item doesn't start on a new line.
  \begin{enumerate*} \item ee \item ff \end{enumerate*}
\item Second.

\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}`. If you prefer, you can pass `[label=(\alph*),itemjoin=\\]` to the inner `enumerate*` environment.

Comment: Unrelated: use a single backtick (`\``) on either side to include code in comments on this site.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I found this doable. But it's not what I want.

Comment: can we apply without newline approach for the all items?

Comment: @alper Simply remove ``itemjoin=\\``.